# Apache loading random Virtual Host file

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I have a server that is hosting multiple sites. One of these sites has an SSL. For some reason if you try to access a site that is not setup for SSL, I get an SSL error because a different site gets loaded. I don't know if that makes sense, but here is an example:

if I got to https://site1.com, apache will load https://site2.com instead of loading the site from default-ssl virtual host file

### Updated

found the problem. What happened was two things:

1. the default-ssl virtual host was not enabled
2. apache does NOT like wild cards. the default had something like *:443, so I changed it to  :443

Comment: Can you add the output of `apachectl -S` to your question?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Once I executed the apachectl, I saw the debug information and managed to fix it. That was extremely helpful. Can you please put that as an answer and I'll add some comments and mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnathanKong You can answer your own question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The virtual host structure, and which one is used as the default, can be a bit finicky - `apachectl -S` gives a good view of the current configuration, including the default virtual hosts on each configured listener.  It's a good place to look for issues with the wrong virtual host being used for requests.

Comment: Right. This gave me all the information I needed. I managed to find out that the default-ssl virtual host file that was setup incorrectly. As mentioned in the answer, it was actually the virtual host file that was setup incorrectly and the apachectl -S shows that it was under the incorrect IP address.